# Trouble creating search in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular's search filter in the following way and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This application should be able to use the search input to search all manufacturer names and items from the controller.

I know it is working somewhat correctly because my browser shows the image and manufacturer.name of both objects: manufacturer1 and manufacturer2, but it is not showing the items and the search function doesn't work.

Help is greatly appreciated! I'm pretty new to Angular.

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">        

    <input type="search" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Manufacturers, Solutions, Equipment, Etc.">    

    <manufacturer info="manufacturer1"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="manufacturer2"></manufacturer>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.manufacturer1 = {
    name: 'Business Name',
    items: [
        'service1',
        'service2',
        'service3'
    ],
    image: 'assets/images/image.png'
};
$scope.manufacturer2 = {
    name: 'Other Business',
    items: [
        'product1',
        'product2',
        'product3'
    ],
    image: 'assets/images/image.png'
};
}]);
```

Directive JS

```
app.directive('manufacturer', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'assets/js/directives/manufacturer.html'
};
});
```

Directive Template:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2 class="business-title">{{ info.name }}</h2>
    <img ng-src="{{ info.image }}" class="feature-img" alt="image"/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
            {{ info.items }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a plunker of the code I am using: http://plnkr.co/edit/IzOfXmD8O09lmdWoictq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `manufacturer` directive has isolated scope, so you couldn't have access to `search` variable inside your directive you need to pass the `search` variable to the directive from the directive `attribute` & include that property inside directive isolated scope, as you have done for the `info` variable.

Basically you need to add `serach: '='` inside your directive isolated scope, which will pass the `search` input box value to the directive by using attribute `search="search"`. `=` is used for two way binding to update the search result as user will change the input the info will get filtered automatically.

**Markup**

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Manufacturers, Solutions, Equipment, Etc.">    
<manufacturer info="manufacturer1" search="search"></manufacturer>
<manufacturer info="manufacturer2" search="search"></manufacturer>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('manufacturer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '=',
        search: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'assets/js/directives/manufacturer.html'
  };
});
```

**Update**

You have wrong html inside your `manufacturer.html`, specifically the content which is showing items using `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in info.items | filter:search">
        {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CVQN1XeapIZOixWvlE9c?p=preview)

Comment: @LanceBeaudry was having typo in `search`..previously it was `serach`

Comment: I caught it and tried and it still doesn't work. Here is a plunker that I added it to: http://plnkr.co/edit/IzOfXmD8O09lmdWoictq?p=preview

Comment: @LanceBeaudry look at edit..you had wrong template..also attached working plunkr

Comment: I knew I was close! That is great. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how I could make the image alt and the manufacturer name searchable as well?

Comment: @LanceBeaudry you could upvote & accept the answer if it does help it..Thanks :)